# Can't get my converter to work

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

Ive tried to make my converter to work but the XAML doesn't know where it is.. but **its there in a folder called Converters.**

**Here how my XAML are setup...**

```xml
Fill="{Binding RequestStatus, Converter={StaticResource converters:StatusToColorConverter}}">
```

**At the top...**

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Exemple8.Convertisseurs">
```

**My converter...**

```vb
Public Class StatusToColorConverter
Implements IValueConverter
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works, [`StaticResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx) references objects added to the `Resources` dictionary on controls and objects, you need to create an instance and reference it by its key or create it right in the `Binding`.

e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:StatusToColorConverter x:Key="StatusToColorConverter"/>
<Window.Resources>
```

```xml
Fill="{Binding RequestStatus, Converter={StaticResource StatusToColorConverter}}">
```

---

```
<XXX.Fill>
    <Binding Path="RequestStatus">
        <Binding.Converter>
            <converters:StatusToColorConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
    <Binding>
</XXX.Fill>
```

Comment: Nice thanks.. look like i was all wrong.. i fellowed some article on this but that might be an old version of the framework.

Comment: @Rushino: Maybe the person just used an odd key for the converter and left out its declaration in the Resources.

Comment: @Rushino: That article just assumes that you know how StaticResource works and that the input is a resource key, as suspected the declaration was omitted.